# Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: css, bootstrap

В общем, загвоздка такая. Изображения из слайдера и переключатели (черные метки, при клике на которые сменяется картинка) не показываются в мобильном разрешении. Сам блок с ними есть и место занимает, но не отображается. Кто может сказать, в чем проблема?

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

         <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/portfolio_slide_1.jpg" alt="1">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/portfolio_slide_2.jpg" alt="2">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/portfolio_slide_3.jpg" alt="3">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: эм, что бы сказать в чем проблема необходимо взглянуть на код.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте подключение стилей. Проверьте, чтобы Ваши стили не перебивали стили индикаторов.

Все работает при любом разрешении:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

         <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="1">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="2">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="3">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```